# Select from two different tables

Tags: sql

So, I have two tables, Table R and Table N. The data in Table R is from Table N. My problem is I don't know the SELECT query that will display the result such as below, because there are 4 names, and SQL can only choose 1. Is there a query or any other way to get the result?

```
Table R:
Id1 Id2 Id3 Id4
1   3   5   7
2   4   6   8

Table N:
Id  Name
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
6   F
7   G
8   H
```

After the SELECT statement, the result should look like this:

```
Name1   Name2   Name3   Name4
A       C       E       G
B       D       F       H
```

Anyway, thanks for helping. ^_^

Comment: That looks like a conception error. You shouldn't design a table like this. What's the real deal?

Comment: I believe you haven't exact idea about the database tables. Your question also looks weird to me

Comment: It could a real life situation. For instance, I got an order table that points to two different addresses (shipping address and billing address), so it contains two address ids.

Comment: Either the tables are badly designed or this is a SQL-101 homework question and Adi is asking us to do his(her?) homework.

Comment: @GolezTrol if that were the case, that would still be a bad design IMO. If you have two address types, you normally would have the order_adress table with an address_type identifier.

Comment: First of all, I made this for reporting. I'm not the one who make all this tables, I'm just continue other people's project. And my main is not in database at all, I'm more to software programming. Anyway, thanks for all the information and knowledge from all of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  N1.Name AS `Name1`,
  N2.Name AS `Name2`,
  N3.Name AS `Name3`,
  N4.Name AS `Name4`
FROM
  R
INNER JOIN
  N N1
ON
  N1.Id = R.Id1
INNER JOIN
  N N2
ON
  N2.Id = R.Id2
INNER JOIN
  N N3
ON
  N3.Id = R.Id3
INNER JOIN
  N N4
ON
  N4.Id = R.Id4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  n1.Name as Name1,
  n2.Name as Name2,
  n3.Name as Name3,
  n4.Name as Name4
from
  R
  inner join N n1 on n1.id = R.id1
  inner join N n2 on n2.id = R.id2
  inner join N n3 on n3.id = R.id3
  inner join N n4 on n4.id = R.id4
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can rename the table in the query
2. You can join the same table multiple times provided you rename it, so:

   ```
   select N1.Name, N2.Name, N3.Name, N4.Name
   from R
   join N as N1 on N1.Id = Id1
   join N as N2 on N2.Id = Id2
   join N as N3 on N3.Id = Id3
   join N as N4 on N4.Id = Id4
   ```

   (of course that's equivalent to

   ```
   select N1.Name, N2.Name, N3.Name, N4.Name
   from R, N as N1, N as N2, N as N3, N as N4
   where N1.Id = Id1 and
       N2.Id = Id2 and
       N3.Id = Id3 and
       N4.Id = Id4
   ```

   (the on clauses are just added to where and comma is join)

Comment: With 'renaming' actually meaning 'aliasing'.